# If this then include that (java password generator)

Tags: java, if-statement, passwords

I am making a password generator and I want the user to have the option to choose if they want to include upper/lower case letters, special chars and numbers but I am not sure how to do this with the code that I have right now without making too many if statements.

```
private static final String ALPHA_CAPS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
private static final String ALPHA = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
private static final String NUMERIC = "0123456789";
private static final String SPECIAL_CHARS = "!@#$%^&*_=+-/";
private static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
```

Above are the different chars that can be used to generate the password.

```
public void generatePasswordAgain(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    genPassword.setText(generatePassword(length, ALPHA_CAPS + ALPHA + SPECIAL_CHARS + NUMERIC));
}
```

Above is the function called when you want to generate a password. And below is the code that actually generates the password.

```
public static String generatePassword(int len, String dic) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int index = random.nextInt(dic.length());
        result += dic.charAt(index);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I want to give the person using the program a chance to choose what type of chars they want to include in their program. Is there a way to do this without making too many if statements?

The persons demands for the chars they want to include are defined by booleans.

Comment: What exactly is your question? You don't know how to execute code on condition?

Comment: OP wants to pass the parameters for generating password based on boolean flags for each type of character set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid switch case and if else cascades, you may use a single line trinary operator.

```
private static final String EMPTY = "";

... // StringUtils.EMPTY can also be used.

boolean alphaUpper, alphaLower, numeric, special;

... // set your boolean flags here

genPassword.setText(generatePassword(length, (alphaUpper ? ALPHA_CAPS : EMPTY) + (alphaLower ? ALPHA : EMPTY) + (special ? SPECIAL_CHARS : EMPTY) + (numeric ? NUMERIC : EMPTY)));
```